# D3D11 SwapChain Buffer is NULL

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, direct3d11

Whenever I run this code, the data that is pointed (member `pData`) to within the _TextureData struct is all 0 (like 300 bytes of just 0). The `HRESULT result` that it returns is always `S_OK`, and the row and column depths are accurate. I am sure that something is being rendered to the buffer because there are things being displayed on the window that I am rendering to. I have tried both getting the buffer's data before and after presenting, and either way, the data is still null.

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc { };
ID3D11Texture2D * pCopy = nullptr;
ID3D11Texture2D * pBackBufferTexture = nullptr;
desc.Width = 800;
desc.Height = 800;
desc.MipLevels = 1;
desc.ArraySize = 1;
desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
desc.BindFlags = 0;
desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
desc.MiscFlags = 0;

assert( SUCCEEDED( pSwapChain->Present( 0,
                                        0 ) ) );
pDevice->CreateTexture2D( &desc, nullptr, &pCopy );
pSwapChain->GetBuffer( 0,
                       __uuidof( ID3D11Texture2D ),
                       reinterpret_cast< void ** >( &pBackBufferTexture ) );
pContext->CopyResource( pCopy, pBackBufferTexture );
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE _TextureData { };
auto result = pContext->Map( pCopy, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &_TextureData );
pContext->Unmap( pCopy, 0 );
pCopy->Release( );
```

Comment: After ``Present`` any scene you've drawn was 'flipped' so the back buffer after that point is the NEXT frame, not the LAST frame.

Comment: I tried getting it before and after presenting and both times the data is all null.

Comment: There's a lot of points here you can get failures that you are not checking, so I don't know exactly what's the problem. That said, if what you are trying to do is basically a 'screenshot' capture, see [ScreenGrab](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ScreenGrab).

Comment: None of the function calls along the way are failing and everything renders properly. I am just trying to get the backbuffer contents of the swapchain before it is swapped with the front buffer. I have tried getting the texture before and after swapping, and neither have worked. I have also tried not clearing my render target view so that nothing is ever cleared from the front / back buffers, and that still had no effect.

Comment: You appear to making assumptions about the size and format of the backbuffer in your staging resource. You should double-check that.

Comment: I have tried getting the description of the backbuffer and setting the format, width, and height of the destination texture to match those of the backbuffer. However, the copy still results in null memory when I do this

Comment: You should post the code you use to create the swap-chain as well as the code to read the size. Right now I'm just guessing blindly

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn https://imgur.com/a/Vk0Bvn2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for the swapchain holds the answer... The swap-chain was created with 4x MSAA, but the staging texture is single-sample.

You can't `CopyResource` in this case. Instead you must resolve the MSAA:

```
pContext->ResolveSubresource(pCopy, 0, pBackBufferTexture, 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM);
```

See the *DirectX Tool Kit* [ScreenGrab](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/ScreenGrab.cpp) source which handles this case more generally.

> The code also shows that you are not using the Debug device (`D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG`) which would have told you about this problem. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/) for details.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I owe you a bushel of apples

Comment: @Chuck Walbourn  Are you interested in a good job? Sorry for writing here, i could not find any other contact method..